# SQL Builder in Talend

Tags: talend, rownum, sqlbuilder

I have to perform incremental load thorough Talend, for that i have to write query in SQL Builder, but it is not returning more than 10 records.

For Oracle code i have Tried below 
1. Checked SQL -Limit number of row - not working
2. ROWNUM < = 100 - not working

Could anyone suggest on this.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your currentJob ? Do you have any error messages ? When you run your query through another tool, do you have more than 10 rows ?

Comment: Yes i have 19 rows in table but from talend it is returning only 10.